# jQuery form serialize - just returns an empty string

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-validate

I am not getting any data from serializing my html form. Here is the form

```
<form method="post" action="#" name='basicForm' id='basicForm'>

<input type="text" name="n_username" id="id_username" class="form-control uname" placeholder='Username' value='test_user' data-msg-required='The input field is required.' data-rule-required='true'/>

<input type="password" name="n_password" id="id_password" class="form-control pword" placeholder='Password' value='xxxx' data-msg-required='The input field is required.' data-rule-required='true'/>                  

<button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Sign In</button> </form>
```

and here is the jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#basicForm").validate({

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var request;
            var $form = $(this);

            var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

            var serializedData = $form.serialize();
            alert (serializedData);  <==empty

            $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

            request = $.ajax({
                url: "./ajax/login.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData
            });

            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // log a message to the console
                console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                alert(response);
                //window.location.replace("success.php");
             });
        }


    }); //validate

});//ready
</script>
```

The data in the form is not serialised. I get an empty alert box. Also on the ajax page i postback to i print_r the $_post array and get this: Array()

I have checked the form elements have names which seems to be the common problem. I am using this jquery version

The validation works fine. This also works

```
var x = $("#id_username").val();
 var y = $("#id_password").val();
request = $.ajax({
                url: "./ajax/login.php",
                type: "post",
                //data: serializedData
                data : {
                    username : x,
                    password: y
                    }
```

thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the problem is that there will be no `$(this)` within the callback function, so his `$form` is empty.

Comment: i;ll check it on monday, im sure it will fix it.what do i write? form_name.serlize?

Comment: i did copy the code of stack oveflow :)

Answer (score 4):

You are breaking it here...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    ...
    var $form = $(this); // <- '$(this)' is meaningless
    ...
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    ...
```

There is no `$(this)` within this context, so your `$form` is empty.

Since the `form` argument representing the `form` object has already been provided by the developer, this version works fine...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    var serializedData = $(form).serialize();
    ...
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/gpaf8187/**

**Note**:  you'll also need a `type="submit"` within your `<button>` element or the validation plugin will not pick up this event.