# Ajax Call on submit handler Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a form which have multiple select dropdown  `name=select[]`, and this form is validate from Jquery Validation and after successful validation Submit handler call Ajax i want to send all form keys and values also include in array form , Here is My Code .

```
function:submitHandler
{
$.ajax({
url: "processo.php", 
type: "POST",             
data: new FormData(this),
cache: false,             
processData:false,      
success: function(data)   
{
$('#loading').hide();
$("#message").html(data);
}
});
}
```

Now the when validation successfully done new FormData(this) not recognize form id.but when i put `new Formdata($("#frmRegister")[0])` then its send variables to php but not array. How can i define form id in like  `new Formdata("#frmRegister")`.Remember please i also have mulitple select array in form .

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?  Why `function: submitHandler`?   Within the `.validate()` method, it should be `submitHandler: function(form) {...}`.  Show the rest of the relevant code in proper context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The `submithandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) goes inside of the `.validate()` method and you would use the `form` argument provided by the developer.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "processo.php", 
            type: "POST",             
            data: new FormData($(form)),
            cache: false,             
            processData: false,      
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#message").html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
    // other options
});
```

[You could also use `$(form).serialize();` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27254314/594235).

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Very Much For giving Answer i have solution here is code .

```
function: submitHandler {
            $("#frmRegister").load("submit", function (e)// Trigger Submit When Validation Done
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "processo.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $("#message").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: But ***where*** is `function:submitHandler{...}` located??  None of this is making any sense within the context of the jQuery Validate plugin.  Are you actually using this plugin as indicated by the tag on your question?

Comment: sorry , but  function:submitHandler dose not exist should be  submitHandler: function(form) as your request .Thanks

Comment: If that's true, then `$("#frmRegister").load("submit")` makes less sense.  You would never put a `load` handler or `submit` event within the `submitHandler` callback function for this plugin.