# Post success function doesn't invoke when from is valid

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form which makes a post request to Node Js, and when submitting - the data is saved in MongoDB. 
I'm trying to validate the form with Jquery Validate.js, when wrong values are inserted to the inputs - error messages appears - but when the form is valid - it keeps redirect to the action url... and by doing so - the post success message isn't displayed.

Here is my js file :

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

            toastr.options = {
                "debug": false,
                "positionClass": "toast-top-full-width",
                "onclick": null,
                "fadeIn": 300,
                "fadeOut": 100,
                "timeOut": 5000,
                "extendedTimeOut": 1000
            };

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("intlTelNumber", function (value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || $(element).intlTelInput("isValidNumber");
            }, function () {
                if (toastr.warning("Warning")) {

                    toastr.clear(getLastToast());
                }
            });

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("isInt", function (value, element) {
                console.log(this.optional(element));
                console.log(value);
                console.log(element);
                return this.optional(element) || !isNaN$(element);

            });

            var options = {
                autoPlaceholder: true,
                preferredCountries: ['al']
            };

            $("#phone").intlTelInput(options);

            $('#submit').click(function () {
                $("#form").validate({
                    rules: {

                        "email": {
                            required: true,

                        }, "phone": {
                            required: true,
                            isInt: true
                        }, "textarea": {

                        }, "country": {

                        }

                    },
                    messages: {

                        "email": {
                            required: function () {
                                toastr.warning("Email is invalid")
                            }

                        },
                        "phone": {
                            required: function () {
                                toastr.warning("phone is invalid")
                            }

                        }
                    }

                });
                if ($('#form').valid()) {


                    var data = {
                        email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                        select: $('#exampleFormControlSelect1').val(),
                        phone: $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
                        country: $("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").iso2,
                        textarea: $('textarea').val()


                    }

                    $.post({

                        data: data,

                        url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint',
                        success: function (data) {

                            toastr.success("Data Saved");

                        }
                    });
                }

                return false;
            });

        });
```

And here is the Html

```
       <form id="form" method="post" action="/endpoint">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" 
                placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example 
                 select</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" 
                   name="select">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone"> multiple select</label>
                <input id="phone" class="form-control" type="tel" 
              name="phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example 
                textarea</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="textarea" rows="3">
         </textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">

        </form>
```

Here is my first attempt with submitHandler

```
          $("#form").validate({
                rules: {

                    "email": {
                        required: true,

                    }, "phone": {
                        required: true,
                        isInt: true
                    }, "textarea": {

                    }, "country": {

                    }

                },
                messages: {

                    "email": {
                        required: function () {
                            toastr.warning("Email is invalid")
                        }

                    },
                    "phone": {
                        required: function () {
                            toastr.warning("phone is invalid")
                        }

                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo

                    var data = {
                        email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
                        select: $('#exampleFormControlSelect1').val(),
                        phone: $('input[name="phone"]').val(),
                        country: $("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").iso2,
                        textarea: $('textarea').val()


                    };

                    $.post({

                        data: data,

                        url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint',
                        success: function (data) {

                            toastr.success("Data Saved");

                        }
                    });
                    return false; // for demo
                }
            });
```

Comment: You should use the `submitHandler` property of the validate plugin to send the form via AJAX after successful validation, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745511/ajax-call-on-submit-handler-jquery-validation)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  this was my first attempt... didn't worked - i updated the question with this attempt.

Comment: Do JSON.stringify(data) and then try.otherwise refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418220/javascript-send-json-object-with-ajax

Comment: @SudhakarAyyar I don't think that will work since the data is saved perfectly..the page is just being redirect...